# Get annotation via field's initial value

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a class Test:

```
public class Test 
{
    @Anno1(Anno1Param = "bla1")
    @Anno2(Anno2Param = "bla1")
    public static final String TEST1 = "test1";

    @Anno1(Anno1Param = "bla2")
    @Anno2(Anno2Param = "bla2")
    @Anno3(Anno3Param = "bla2")
    public static final String TEST2 = "test2";

    @Anno3(Anno3Param = "bla3")
    public static final String TEST3 = "test3";

    @Anno1(Anno1Param = "bla4")
    public static final String TEST4 = "test4";
}
```

now, given field value, I want to retrieve the annotation associated with it. The only way I can do it now is:

```
 for (Field field : Test.class.getFields()) {
     if(field.get(this).equals("test4")) {
         Annotation a = field.getAnnotation(Anno1.class);
         ......
     }
 }
```

Is there a way in java reflection I can do something like:

```
getAnnotationByFieldValue("test4")
```

so that given the field value "test4", without iterating through all the fields in Test class and retrieve the annotation reference directly?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and if there were it would only be doing the same iteration internally.

Comment: No, you'll have to iterate. You can, of course, cache the result of mapping the values to the fields so you only have to do the lookup once per value.